# Find the path of a node in a binary tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, heapsort

I have a struct that describes a node of a binary tree:

```
struct node{
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int number_of_nodes;
}
```

As you see there is no parent node. So if I wanted to find a node I would have to know the path in advance to get to it.
Here's an example:

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
  / \ / \
 4  5 6  7
```

If for example the node I want to visit is 6 I should know the path to go there.
The problem is that I am not allowed to use any data structures either static or dynamic to save the path. I am supposed to find the path for every node from the number_of_nodes, but I can't figure it out.

I am really struggling with this. Any help will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem description appears to be incomplete.  You don't need to know the path in advance to find a given node. If this is a homework assignment, you should ask for clarity from the instructor.

Comment: Maybe I wrote it incompletly. That is exactly what he says: "During the construction or updating of the Heap we start to insert the new element always from the root to the leaves, calculating the tree path based on the number of nodes".

Comment: Is this what you are doing?  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/

Comment: @Robert Harvey I forgot to tag you in the comment

Comment: The instruction you quote speaks of a heap... There is no mention of a heap in your question. And *constructing* and *updating* is not the same thing as *finding*. Those are entirely different operations. It would help if you would quote the assignment literally in the question so we have complete information.

Comment: @trincot Well you are right but I didn't want to share the whole project. Indeed the project is about heapsort but the spot I was struggling was what I wrote.  I needed to know the path of a node so I can move to it from the root directly. No recursion or anything like fifo data structure can be used.

Comment: I see there is no progress here. The thing is that without more information, to find a path to any given node you'll have to traverse the tree in search for the node without any advantage. `number_of_nodes` is not of any help here. If this concerns a heap (as you mentioned in a previous comment) then this search will kill any advantage that a heap offers. It makes no sense. It would be a different story if it were a binary search tree.